# Lookup/Find within a set area

Tags: excel, vba

When I replace "Activesheet.cells" in the "lFundcolumn" below with "rnMonths" I'm getting a "Run time error 13".  I would be grateful if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong here please.

In short - I want to find a value within a row and copy that column and the column to the right of it.  Below is the code for locating the first column which is erroring.

```
Sub Roll_period()

Dim sMonth As String
Dim rnMonths As Range
Dim lFundcolumn As Long
Dim rnRngtocopy As Range
    sMonth = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value
    Set rnMonths = ActiveSheet.Rows(4)


lFundcolumn = rnMonths.Find(What:=sMonth, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

Comment: John's answer will address your issue, but I'd also suggest checking the return value of `.Find()` before checking its `.Column` property, or you'll get an error when the value is not found (because the `Find()` will return `Nothing` instead of a Range object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... You did everything right, your issue was `after:=ActiveCell` in your `Find` statement, which may or may not point to the right place to look...

Change it to this:

```
after:=rnMonths.Cells(1, 1)
```

Which would look like:

```
lFundcolumn = rnMonths.Find(What:=sMonth, after:=rnMonths.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

Hope that does the trick!!

Comment: Thanks for your input John.  Apreciate the help.  It seems straight forward once you point out the error.